# Lots of broken source and class path errors in IntelliJ spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle

I recently lost my main Linux development system due to a motherboard failure.  Because of this, I had to install on a completely different PC (different manufacturer and motherboard model).  Therefore I couldn't use my image backup to restore because I needed a Fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 because of the difference in PC configuration.

I am now close to having it rebuilt, having done a ton of copying from my non-image backups (rsync, etc.).  However, when I go into one of my IntelliJ Java projects that used to work fine, I am getting a *lot* of broken source and class path errors when I examine the project settings.  They are all gradle library paths.  I am currently using Gradle 4.3, which I confirmed using the sdkman list command (sdk list gradle).  Also, I am using version 172.4343.14 of the IntelliJ Gradle plug-in.  I am using IntelliJ IDE version 2017.2.5

How can I fix these errors (shown below)?

```
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.4.7.RELEASE/a214a618f03f764b212523851c9afc7122179429/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.4.7.RELEASE/9b639ebea41f1f5dff91c9feb752ab9556902e0b/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.4.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-test/1.4.7.RELEASE/1a4f4231a61b99d516d06bc77f969d78e78116ff/spring-boot-test-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-test/1.4.7.RELEASE/8016c3bc9c7465fc9a350d230d184f99c12bdac6/spring-boot-test-1.4.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/1.4.7.RELEASE/e871387535de39baec6dcd0b6bbb95e36379c2e9/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/1.4.7.RELEASE/efc331fafe73763575b949fdf55bb845e7a1f10b/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.4.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.15.Final has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.15.Final/c06dbf0f4119fdbb3db6ff880b38e835766455b2/netty-codec-http-4.1.15.Final.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.15.Final has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.15.Final/fae9b7302b625a68505bdb4e1de7b2692bb17269/netty-codec-http-4.1.15.Final-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.8.8 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.8.8/e70be1cd2ad47615a527f7475f63acadbf3be730/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.8.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.8.8 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.8.8/475f3bd82ccd8ec51adfe4c429d40c22d4191d0b/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.8-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-redis/1.4.7.RELEASE/8bdfd1068ee4d3720386070c4003a68cc33cf1/spring-boot-starter-redis-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-redis/1.4.7.RELEASE/11cc1b8e0cf8e3710713bdaf32d0d4052f13b823/spring-boot-starter-redis-1.4.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.15.Final has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec/4.1.15.Final/15cef796196b4027911d5de8a3f0d333842896d1/netty-codec-4.1.15.Final.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.15.Final has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec/4.1.15.Final/2ac10a559671570fd9c7cc21dffa8f856307d148/netty-codec-4.1.15.Final-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.undertow:undertow-core:1.3.28.Final has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.undertow/undertow-core/1.3.28.Final/dcf5bfe6bae91e0bc8e1d7a8a53273d81a1dae4f/undertow-core-1.3.28.Final.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.undertow:undertow-core:1.3.28.Final has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.undertow/undertow-core/1.3.28.Final/eb905ad77ec5bb0ae121ecb5f6a3e3fe032af769/undertow-core-1.3.28.Final-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.15.Final has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-resolver/4.1.15.Final/89565523e45aa99af2aa263900a75eb8836b3a47/netty-resolver-4.1.15.Final.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.15.Final has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-resolver/4.1.15.Final/b4f2ed6aefd37cdd7cdddd5e3b535aeff6c43c58/netty-resolver-4.1.15.Final-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.3.0/af000bec2036a2a9d07197c4b03b8966bfc60b03/rxjava-1.3.0.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.3.0/5a34ce3b9e72e2a99b7a86d6e1910785be1a3e3f/rxjava-1.3.0-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.9.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.3.9.RELEASE/91dae64c4280093ad5fb4736a10913c9233479c1/spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.9.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.3.9.RELEASE/ac31864038a1c31d5a49c1bef84e5af4a162a655/spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.3 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.undertow:undertow-websockets-jsr:1.3.28.Final has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.undertow/undertow-websockets-jsr/1.3.28.Final/71383abc611211b50353c2d30eda1da581993bfa/undertow-websockets-jsr-1.3.28.Final.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.undertow:undertow-websockets-jsr:1.3.28.Final has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.undertow/undertow-websockets-jsr/1.3.28.Final/9929153de11ef969d7e68301cb04dd53cca41931/undertow-websockets-jsr-1.3.28.Final-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:1.2.0 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.jpountz.lz4/lz4/1.2.0/cd301e9a481eae5b68c53267100aeca43b782b9f/lz4-1.2.0.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:1.2.0 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.jpountz.lz4/lz4/1.2.0/8ebc24fe8c0dfded99582ecb5baac7a49f23a954/lz4-1.2.0-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.json:json:20140107 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.15.Final has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-buffer/4.1.15.Final/f7edf6488292b4de584ce16acc64f611d76fe4e7/netty-buffer-4.1.15.Final.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.15.Final has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-buffer/4.1.15.Final/151bdb55a25d776ff2a4a16578016c0270047f8a/netty-buffer-4.1.15.Final-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:1.1.9.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons/1.1.9.RELEASE/d6b9891d82eb5b419e12cabd62266ab73a157a6f/spring-cloud-commons-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:1.1.9.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons/1.1.9.RELEASE/7c9f3e09dad3e2b13d06293a13b484fa54378dc5/spring-cloud-commons-1.1.9.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.1.7 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java/1.1.1.7/33b6965e9364145972035c30a45a996aad2bf789/snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.1.7 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java/1.1.1.7/99ad611939e0d2c5d539fe09fb97f761824f5137/snappy-java-1.1.1.7-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:5.0.3 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.woodstox/woodstox-core/5.0.3/10aa199207fda142eff01cd61c69244877d71770/woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:5.0.3 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.woodstox/woodstox-core/5.0.3/f38482e8b060d9e5354c10103f4c4db53c58db7d/woodstox-core-5.0.3-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-archaius:1.2.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-archaius/1.2.7.RELEASE/19da3a169733ec05dfd356f7a7fcbb6698b2c237/spring-cloud-starter-archaius-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-archaius:1.2.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-archaius/1.2.7.RELEASE/d71fa7dbc26664bfe71468c1e6a4889f18011745/spring-cloud-starter-archaius-1.2.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.spockframework/spock-core/1.1-groovy-2.4/1c42014d4a18995d5d4aa10a4e060e88f60fdf78/spock-core-1.1-groovy-2.4.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.spockframework/spock-core/1.1-groovy-2.4/2b08ca54637337988a8da795c6dc3f66d2810ebb/spock-core-1.1-groovy-2.4-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.8.8 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.8.8/778f71765e683037bc8f6440d6afaceb91085852/jackson-datatype-joda-2.8.8.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.8.8 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.8.8/e35b62b3de502b02e77e4a5f2f64ee1125d32d11/jackson-datatype-joda-2.8.8-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.9.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.3.9.RELEASE/4edca6913da9e62a6586714e053e01a61952a153/spring-expression-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.9.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.3.9.RELEASE/7da08664ab1c1d70808ce6eb9b082c7ee9579aad/spring-expression-4.3.9.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.9.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.3.9.RELEASE/a186823724f03b98becd5f93b1fa107fe6f7a7ff/spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.9.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.3.9.RELEASE/c22b7284000897b976c9ee6c12f74f6bc3a35ccc/spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.4.7.RELEASE/1a0187a8fbd4cbf03063ca9ed7366e1a6d1b6640/spring-boot-actuator-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.4.7.RELEASE/21fe7686ef18552df618183aa1a2fb0be9479bb/spring-boot-actuator-1.4.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.4.7.RELEASE/3e77db6ed4b3f698909be8ae0b38ff0c2df9fad6/spring-boot-starter-web-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.4.7.RELEASE/eb38ab2a338d4650c05ba451cc00911122736f90/spring-boot-starter-web-1.4.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.8.8 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.8.8/345a87f3c145912163964ded45803ebf0a9c775e/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.8.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.8.8 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.8.8/d82d580f8a9a69b506f944b58b35d97ed8552233/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.8-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.lmax:disruptor:3.3.6 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.lmax/disruptor/3.3.6/9bfca4ee4f691f3737b3f4f006d0c4770f178eb/disruptor-3.3.6.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.lmax:disruptor:3.3.6 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.lmax/disruptor/3.3.6/73526450212ef3191de4b956e53e48b9987d766c/disruptor-3.3.6-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.15.Final has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport/4.1.15.Final/46e3f244f26422b3cfb5ffc5c2d9984b7725ed89/netty-transport-4.1.15.Final.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.15.Final has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport/4.1.15.Final/927decaeb1388f94a462c65a127999aa2fa8fd4a/netty-transport-4.1.15.Final-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.4.7.RELEASE/1a73f7004206cdb0de23f1e63b8c1c9c6c0db4e/spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.4.7.RELEASE/1a3cb002d5ff0d6ff0ae1965dc6c7632d62d006b/spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.9.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.9.RELEASE/ca80b4a00abc388d8046bf372099f35564371c47/spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.9.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.9.RELEASE/d40a14cdad9b34e6bc1a547345fb16d8fe3092c0/spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: net.minidev:accessors-smart:1.1 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.m2/repository/net/minidev/accessors-smart/1.1/accessors-smart-1.1-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.8.8 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.8.8/3f5e135fd48af6c7fb432166c5b658e9133114ea/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.8.8.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.8.8 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.8.8/7a6816c22f217bc5173b6126a8250ffed40bc271/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.8.8-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.83 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.83/9cd9c5ec05ae7a82d6cc3f8856435113d60066fb/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.83.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.83 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.83/12ea3b0ad59f768718f6630536df451835b9992d/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.83-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.bugsnag:bugsnag:2.0.0 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.bugsnag/bugsnag/2.0.0/2e3f3ec327eef6d950da44868d6a5f95bd71c753/bugsnag-2.0.0.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.bugsnag:bugsnag:2.0.0 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.bugsnag/bugsnag/2.0.0/6d133dec0af95ddc950279ce88e4891e92d4924d/bugsnag-2.0.0-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:1.1.9.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter/1.1.9.RELEASE/b11668cfa912c45395fb04294c7304c00cce08d5/spring-cloud-starter-1.1.9.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:1.1.9.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter/1.1.9.RELEASE/7749b6c0734c2832a3f4e61cdb17cae8486bc80b/spring-cloud-starter-1.1.9.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:1.11.83 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kinesis/1.11.83/b941b7a27fa2e10c5f3448bc22435d1c4acbe85f/aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.11.83.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:1.11.83 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kinesis/1.11.83/7b871838c0b68369d25a108ff65d7aa176ca7843/aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.11.83-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.4.7.RELEASE/9c55355d79dc5adb0d53e55f286ae30933782c34/spring-boot-starter-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.4.7.RELEASE/1dafd47f37cace2b9e6c4309cb8e61b892cacf01/spring-boot-starter-1.4.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:1.2.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.2.7.RELEASE/f633aa61c0a686e91ce500a67ed052bc6697250b/spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:1.2.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.2.7.RELEASE/8f4ad4ee43743f902fb3f65580aa4bbc743934cd/spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/1.4.7.RELEASE/deb61e1cae2bf540e9b636f09df89bad9be3ace4/spring-boot-starter-log4j2-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/1.4.7.RELEASE/6720feb7f687adb0daef3c904d1fc685926cf0f/spring-boot-starter-log4j2-1.4.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.4.7.RELEASE/4180347d8c3cd93ac7e6cb46edbea3d0b4e7a58c/spring-boot-starter-test-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.4.7.RELEASE/39f0de86c3d9581094c61a28885ce7a05ab87522/spring-boot-starter-test-1.4.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:1.4.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-undertow/1.4.7.RELEASE/a0d1d8fe551dc3ab0cba82c3069de1736900fad4/spring-boot-starter-undertow-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.8.2.2 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.8.2.2/a4903cb5fe087be183a50f6c2b08483cff1e8444/kafka-clients-0.8.2.2.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.8.2.2 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.8.2.2/a6385adf1c5827021aa6b78e3f577eca4e6dc8be/kafka-clients-0.8.2.2-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.12.11.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/1.12.11.RELEASE/ac256a5df93c0c62d2ea3c835d0454f97bc5678c/spring-data-commons-1.12.11.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.12.11.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/1.12.11.RELEASE/d0c93186f184ecbff7af3a6e39aa1cb2a0726ee3/spring-data-commons-1.12.11.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.1/objenesis-2.1-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:4.1.15.Final has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.15.Final/cfcdbc196a6f3b5ba94e87c74321bf084e86a673/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.15.Final.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:4.1.15.Final has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.15.Final/faa0bb9dbb63387eadbe6011da4579c15184b885/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.15.Final-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: net.minidev:json-smart:2.2.1 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.2.1/json-smart-2.2.1-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1-groovy-2.4 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.spockframework/spock-spring/1.1-groovy-2.4/ba2e752469f955e76cfdb61cd64a36089619e05f/spock-spring-1.1-groovy-2.4.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1-groovy-2.4 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.spockframework/spock-spring/1.1-groovy-2.4/73b9a95b871c1a8eb69a5dc3e77e6ebbd44fc72e/spock-spring-1.1-groovy-2.4-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.8.8 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.8.8/e2e95efc46d45be4b429b704efbb1d4b89721d3a/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.8.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.8.8 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.8.8/c4cc9060f3419266688a8906c0a58573290612b0/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.8-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.3.9.RELEASE/430b7298bfb85d66fb61e19ca8f06231b911e9f5/spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.3.9.RELEASE/f85656c1404f6e4fddbc1ca2180748856880913f/spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14 has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/775b7e22fb10026eed3f86e8dc556dfafe35f2d5/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14 has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/886474da3f761d39fcbb723d97ecc5089e731f42/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14-sources.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:1.2.7.RELEASE has broken classes path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/1.2.7.RELEASE/72aeca646cc548f20e3a32a033a340aa478183ab/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar [Fix]
    Library Gradle: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:1.2.7.RELEASE has broken sources path:   /home/robert/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/1.2.7.RELEASE/7edfabdfc8e7a5310a56a72bb65e32dd4a5a739a/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.7.RELEASE-sources.jar [Fix]
```

Comment: Reimport the Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA so that it downloads and refreshes all the dependencies.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - I just had to run "./gradlew clean build" and it downloaded all the needed dependencies.  See my comment to Khalid Abu El-Soud

Comment: Gradle project refresh in IntelliJ IDEA would do the same with one click.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks.  If you're so inclined, please promote your comment to a full answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Refresh Gradle Projects in the [Gradle Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-tool-window.html), it will download all the missing dependencies.

[image: refresh]

Comment: If you don't find above options of a refresh loop. 
Goto ==> Task Menu "Build" ==> "Build project"

Answer (score 5):

try to remove caches under

> /home/robert/.gradle/

and rebuild the project

Or you can use following command to refresh the gradle and download any missing or broken dependencies:

> ./gradlew clean build

Comment: I recently did a "./gradlew clean build" command and it solved the problems.  I forgot that you operation examins the gradle build file and downloads missing packages.  If you add that information to your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It seems that I arrived late, anyway I've update my answer to be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

I tried View -> tools window -> Gradle -> then refresh button. It took time to update Gradle dependencies but now errors of broken class path were removed.